# Right-wing authoritarianism (RWA) and Social-dominance orientation (SDO) in the World Values Survey

Tags: social-psychology, political-psychology

[Right-wing authoritarianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-wing_authoritarianism) (RWA) and [Social-dominance orientation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_dominance_orientation) (SDO) are two measures often used in (social) psychology studies on political orientation, see e.g. a meta-analysis of [Sibley and Duckitt](https://doi.org/10.1177%2F1088868308319226) linking them to Big-Five personality factors, or another of [Onraet et al.](https://doi.org/10.1002/per.2027) relating them to cognitive abilities.

On the other hand there's a large dataset from the [World Values Survey](http://www.worldvaluessurvey.org/WVSContents.jsp) (WVS) that also asks left-right political orientation questions; see for instance [Geser (2008)](http://geser.net/internat/t_hgeser5.pdf). It seems to me sociologists and political scientists rather than psychologists have more often used this dataset.

So, my questions is: are the RWA and SDO measures well correlated with some subset of World Values Survey questions? I.e., can a subset of the latter be used to stand-in for the two more specific instruments?

(This may seem like an odd question, i.e. why use a big questionnaire instead of two small ones, but the WVS dataset covers a lot of countries, in many of which one can hardly find a single RWA/SDO study.)

Comment: I'm trying to answer the exact same question, and from what I've read so far in the SDO/RWA literature I would say no one has actually tried correlating these, or if they have it hasn't been published anywhere I've seen. I've just had a brief read through the WVS questions for two waves and there are definitely a lot of questions that seem to conceptually tap into either RWA or SDO. How well or comprehensively they do this, I'm not sure. This is probably more to do with "who has the time to do this" than any theoretical reasons. If my PhD study doesn't pan out I might just look into this.